# react-router v4 alpha7 +dom6 not pushing context through BrowserRouter

Tags: react-router

With react-router v4 alpha7 and dom alpha6 (latest versions) i get the following error:

```
Warning: Failed context type: The context `router` is marked as required in `Link`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in Link (created by MainComponent)
    in p (created by MainComponent)
    in div (created by MainComponent)
    in MainComponent (created by Route)
    in Route
    in div
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter
    in ApolloProvider
```

I have seen similar questions like this, but i followed their advice.

BrowserRouter is a top level component around router components

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import ApolloClient, { createNetworkInterface } from 'apollo-client';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import MainComponent from './components/main.jsx';
import AboutComponent from './components/about.jsx';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const client = new ApolloClient({
  networkInterface: createNetworkInterface({ uri: 'http://app.local:8001/graphql' }),
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Route exactly path="/" component={MainComponent} />
            <Route path="/about" component={AboutComponent} />
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('tourapp')
)
```

Then there is the `main.jsx`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class MainComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <p><Link to="/about">About</Link></p>
    </div>;
  }
}

export default MainComponent
```

Does anyone have an idea why the router context is not passed? This is almost straightfoward from the docs.

Comment: problem was inconsistent versions, react-router changes context variables names from beta.6 to beta.7. so it works with both versions beta.6

Comment: I am using beta.6 and I am facing the same issue, I couldn't solve it

Comment: I am using beta.8 which is using react-router 8 version, its solved now

Answer (score 0):

Do this, the link has to be inside the Router tag

```
            <div>
                <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <div className="navbar-header">
                            <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
                        </div>
                        <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li className="active"><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to='/about'>About</Link></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>

                <Switch>

                    <Route exact path="/" component={Weather}/>
                    <Route path="/about" component={About}/>

                </Switch>
            </div>



        </Router>
```